# Error HTTPSConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with url: (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, proxies

I have purchased a bot from a developer who provided an .exe and a .py file. The .exe works completely fine and accepts my proxies.

I have needed to make minor design changes as the end result is outputted to a discord bot however when I try run both the original and the new script I receive the error above.

Imports at top of script:

```
from discord import Embed, Streaming, Color
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from re import search
import os
import sys
```

My PIP list:

```
https://pastebin.com/0jZB6i5f
```

My pyinstaller error log from when I try compile to an .exe;

```
https://pastebin.com/8Zy0zxh8
```

I have tried installing every one of these but they either give out errors or say they are already installed. Even after succesfully installing some they don't disappear. I have updated my RDP, installed certificates and so on and am currently pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.